# Foreach inside if() | if() close issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, foreach

I am putting a foreach statement inside an if statement and am having an issue closing the if statement.  The if checks for a "type", if the entry type matches the "type" selected it will output  all entries with that "type" with the foreach.

Here's an example.

```
<?php 
  if($row->type == 'HTML')
  {
    foreach($content as $row): ?>
       <h2><?= $row->title ?></h2> 
       <span class="rating"> <?= $row->rating?>/5</span>
       <p class="desc"><?= $row->description ?> </p>
       <span class="date"><?= $row->created ?> </span>
       <a href="<?= $row->url ?>">View Tutorial</a>
       <span class="diff"><?= $row->difficulty ?></span>
       <span class="auth">Added by </span> 
<?php } else {
      echo 'No results found';
 }
 endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will found `$row` in loop so keep `if() else` in foreach for get `$row->type`

```
  <?php 
    foreach($content as $row): 
     if($row->type == 'HTML')
      {?>
       <h2><?= $row->title ?></h2> 
       <span class="rating"> <?= $row->rating?>/5</span>
       <p class="desc"><?= $row->description ?> </p>
       <span class="date"><?= $row->created ?> </span>
       <a href="<?= $row->url ?>">View Tutorial</a>
       <span class="diff"><?= $row->difficulty ?></span>
       <span class="auth">Added by </span> 
    <?php } else {
      echo 'No results found';
 }
endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
foreach($content as $row):
    if($row->type == 'HTML') { ?>
        <h2><?= $row->title ?></h2> <span class="rating"> <?= $row->rating?>/5</span>
        <p class="desc"><?= $row->description ?> </p>
        <span class="date"><?= $row->created ?> </span>
        <a href="<?= $row->url ?>">View Tutorial</a>
        <span class="diff"><?= $row->difficulty ?></span>
        <span class="auth">Added by </span> 
    <?php 
    } else {
        echo 'No results found';
    }
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: really a great understanding of question. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is supposed to be:

- If

  - foreach

    - content
  - end foreach
- else

  - else content
- end if

Your structure is

- If

  - foreach

    - content
- else

  - else content
- end if

  - **end foreach**

You are probably looking for this:

```
<?php 
$found = FALSE; // used to track whether something has been found.
foreach($content as $row){
   if($row->type == 'HTML')
   {
       $found = TRUE; // there is at least one row with ->type == 'HTML'
       ?>
       <h2><?= $row->title ?></h2> 
       <span class="rating"> <?= $row->rating?>/5</span>
       <p class="desc"><?= $row->description ?> </p>
       <span class="date"><?= $row->created ?> </span>
       <a href="<?= $row->url ?>">View Tutorial</a>
       <span class="diff"><?= $row->difficulty ?></span>
       <span class="auth">Added by </span> 
    <?php 
   }
 }; // moved to the {} closing
 // test whether any valid rows have been found (set above)
 if(!$found){echo 'No results found';}
 ?>
```

Comment: if you find this answer useful please mark as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You condition must be this:

```
<?php 
    foreach($content as $row): ?>
      if($row->type == 'HTML')
      {
       <h2><?= $row->title ?></h2> 
       <span class="rating"> <?= $row->rating?>/5</span>
       <p class="desc"><?= $row->description ?> </p>
       <span class="date"><?= $row->created ?> </span>
       <a href="<?= $row->url ?>">View Tutorial</a>
       <span class="diff"><?= $row->difficulty ?></span>
       <span class="auth">Added by </span> 
     <?php } else {
         echo 'No results found';
      }
     ?>
  <?php   endforeach; ?>
```

Your foreach condition should be above of if else condition.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the guy above beat you to it.